# voting to close a question when the question has been reopened

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, closed-questions

A recent question about determining [whether an array of length N containing integers from 1 to N is a permutation in O(N) time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058172/tricky-algorithm-interview-question) was a duplicate of [a previous question that was stated slightly differently but equivalently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872959/algorithm-how-to-tell-if-an-array-is-a-permutation-in-on/2874631#2874631).

I cast one of the votes to close, and the question was eventually closed.

Now it has been reopened, and I cannot vote to close again. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't vote to close twice, or open twice, it has to be a new 5 (or less with a moderator) people who do the open/close each time.  Otherwise it could be a non-stop open/close war between the same small group of people.

Comment: hmm, i guess that makes sense.